How do you implement sign-in with Google using FastHTML
I would like to enable signing in with Google OAuth using FastHTML but can't get it working. I'm looking for minimal sample app that shows how to do it.

This looks promising https://blog.authlib.org/2020/fastapi-google-login

What issues are you seeing with your approach? OAuth has a specification that you can follow and implement the flow by yourself
